# problem when installing vlc on ubuntu 15.04 its taken more than 10 hrs but not successfully installed and give the msg

Tags: apt, 15.04, dependencies, vlc

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.1-2~ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libavcodec56 (>= 6:11~beta1) but it is not installable or
                libavcodec-extra-56 (>= 6:11.2) but it is not installable
       Depends: libavutil54 (>= 6:11~beta1) but it is not installable
       Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.1.0) but it is not installable
       Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not installable
       Depends: libva-drm1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
       Depends: libva-x11-1 (>= 1.0.3) but it is not installable
       Depends: libva1 (>= 1.2.0) but it is not installable
       Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0~pre1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.1-2~ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.1-2~ppa1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at end of your output:

```
Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

To fix broken packages, run

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And then try again installing vlc

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```